# Missing Posts under WINFORMS tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

There used to be thousand of posts under the tag [WINFORMS]. As of now, there are only two.

What happened?

Comment: I also find it a bit confusing, but the question really should go to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: perhaps ... but since this issue MAY only be related to missing WINFORMS posts at SO, I posted it here.

Comment: *facepalm* *facepalm*

Comment: We don't need a [`winforms`] tag on MetaSO, so I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All winforms questions have been retagged windows-forms as many other tags have been retagged. See [The Great Tagging Reorg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg)

Answer (score 1):

I think this change has been reverted and [winforms] is now the correct tag, yes?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/windows-forms-winforms

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for any confusion. If you think this is in error, let me know.

Comment: I'm of the belief that this is in error: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/windows-forms-winforms - I have seen WinForms used as a term in CVs, put not "Windows Forms". This also lacks symmetry with [wpf]